# HTML/PHP: How to pass the value of a dynamic button?

Tags: php, html

I have a form of different types of input fields. It looks something like this:

```
<form action="function.php" method="POST" ...>
   <select name="table" ...>
      <option> ... </option>
      <option> ... </option
   </select>

   <select name="column" ...>
      <option> ... </option>
      <option> ... </option
   </select>

   <input type="text" name="searchword">

   <input type="button" name="operator" value="=" id="operator" onclick="change(this.id)">


   <input type="submit" ...>
</form>
```

With my dynamic button, I can switch the operators (=, <, >) with my "change()" function which I need to create my queries. In my function.php file, I'm trying to get all the values of my input fields ...

```
$table = $_POST["table"];
$column = $_POST["column"];
$operator = $_POST["operator"];
```

... but unfortunately, it only works for the table and for the column input. I can't store the value of my operator button. I tried to find a solution for my problem but most people wrote that I have to change my button's input type to "submit" to pass the value. However, I do not want the action to be executed directly when this button is pressed, but only when the real "submit" button is pressed.

**Edit:**
Here is my "change()" function:

```
function change(operatorId) {
      let element = document.getElementById(operatorId);     
      if (element.value == "=") {
         element.value = ">";
      } else if (element.value == ">") {
         element.value = "<";
      } else if (element.value == "<") {
         element.value = "=";
      }
   }
```

And this is the error message I get when the function.php file opens: "Undefined array key "operator" in ..."

**Edit: Solution**
Thanks to Professor Abronsius' answer, I was able to resolve my problem. As he suggested, I inserted another hidden input field with the name "operator" and changed my button to "operator-selector". In this way, I just had to add some lines to my function to change the hidden field's value. This is how it looks like now:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="operator" id="operator" value="">
<input type="button" name="select-operator" value="=" id="select-operator" onclick="change(this.id)">
```

```js
function change(selectorOperatorId) {
    let selector = document.getElementById(selectorOperatorId);
    
    if (selector.value == "=") {
        selector.value = ">";
        document.getElementById("operator").value = selector.value;
    } else if (selector.value == ">") {
        selector.value = "<";
        document.getElementById("operator").value = selector.value;
    } else if (selector.value == "<") {
        selector.value = "=";
        document.getElementById("operator").value = selector.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What happens instead? How is that markup changed through JS?

Comment: Also, I hope that "create my queries" involves a secure way of generating them, to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: please add the `change` function. Incidentally there is no need at all to change the button to a `submit` in order that you can pass the value

Comment: fyi: `</form action>` is incorrect.... remove `action` from there

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I added the function and I also edited the </form action> part... that was a mistake, but I don't have it in the code.
I also added the error message I get when running the php script.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Why do you need a button for this, which might not get submitted if any other button is used to submit the form?

Comment: @NicoHaase Of course, I could just use a dropdown menu, which will also work 100%. But I want to try it with a dynamic button, because I like it better. And so far I have only tried to change the input type (from "button" to "submit").

Comment: Generally, I don't endorse inline javascript event listeners, but why don't we see `onclick=this.value = {'=':'>','>':'<','<':'='}[this.value];`? (Not tested)

Comment: @mickmackusa This method also works and I like it because it is much more compact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could possibly do would be to keep the button as a regular button but change it's name and then add a hidden input named `operator` - the value can be assigned by the `change` function and will appear in the POST array.

Incidentally I had already written the alternative `change` function below before I saw the edited question. It does have the advantage of being easily extensible if other operators were required/possible.

If the button were changed to a `submit` the `change` function would need to have the `event` passed in as an argument and then call `event.preventDefault();` to stop the form from actually being submitted.

```js
const change=function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//if the button was a `submit` button this would stop the form being submitted.
  const operators=['=','>','<'];
  const input=this.parentNode.operator;


  let i=Number( this.dataset.i );
  let j=i < operators.length-1 ? i+1 : 0;
  this.dataset.i=j;
  input.value=this.value=operators[j]
}
document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="op-selector"]').addEventListener('click',change);
```

```html
<form method='POST'>
   <select name='table'>
    <option>coffee
    <option>dining
   </select>

   <select name='column'>
    <option>doric
    <option>corinthian
   </select>

   <input type='text' name='searchword' />
   <input type='hidden' name='operator' />
   <!--
    the button appears the same but now sets the value of the real `operator`
    field.
   -->
   <input type='button' name='op-selector' data-i=0 value='=' />
   
   <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For some reasons, I can run the code snippet here and it works fine, but when I copy the code, it doesn't work for me. Is there something you also included?

Comment: No - what you see above is what there is. Perhaps share how you have implemented this - we might identify an issue ?!

Comment: In the console, this message is displayed: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". I really have it exactly the same as you. But it's ok, with your help I could resolve the problem. I added the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change input type from **button** to **submit** and then you can access button value with `$_POST["operator"];`

```html
<input type="submit" name="operator" value="=" id="operator" onclick="change(this.id)">
```

If you're using a style framework and don't want your button type to get affected add another hidden field with text type and change its value programmatically.

> **value**
> Defines the value associated with the button’s name when it’s submitted with the form data. This value is passed to the server in params when the form is submitted using this button.

As documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: I don't want to use this button as a submit button, I just want to select an operator in a fancy way other than with a dropdown menu. The whole form should be submitted by the last button. I hope that I have understood your answer correctly.

Comment: @mattmeggZ Try `onclick="change(this.id); return false;"` this will prevent your form from submitting.

Comment: Now the function is called correctly and the form is not submitted immediately, but I still get the error message "Undefined array key "operator" ... "